# How to convert a date type input to a timestamp

Tags: javascript, html

I need to convert the date that I am getting from an HTML5 date input to a timestamp and save it as a variable.

HTML:

```
<form>
<section class="input">
  <input type="date" id="date" name="maintenanace_date"/>  
</section>
<section class="input">
   <input type="time" id="time" name="maintenance_time" placeholder="EST"/>
</section>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save" it as a variable?

Comment: The question is actually quite clear. How to convert an HTML `<input type="date">` with JavaScript to a timestamp.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(document.getElementById("time").value);
var timestamp = date.getTime();
```

If you need to use it in a serverside language like PHP, you also need to divide it by 1000.

However, this depends on the format the date is entered in. If you're using a non-default date format, you'll need to split it up and convert it into year, month and date before instantiating the Date object.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. To do this with Angular 1.5.x, just use `$scope.myTimestamp = $scope.myDate.getTime();`. See [this part](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) of the documentation.